# Create docker image from existing virtual machine

Tags: docker, centos, virtual-machine

I need to create docker base image with CentOS and MySQL. But I already have such VM (without docker on it). How can I create base docker image from this existing VM and use it on another machine with docker?

Answer (score 20):

While the other commenters have pointed out correctly that importing a VM into Docker is not the intended way to create images, *it is possible* and can provide you with a fast starting point to test things before you fully commit. To do this, you simply provision a linux root file system (in your case: your CentOS VM) and stream it into docker import like so:

```
tar -cC [folder containing provisioned root fs] . | docker import - [image name]
```

[Docker's base image documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/) has more info and even links to a script to create a CentOS base image.

Comment: @stepf- can you explain in more detail. I know you are correct but I'm not able to understand how I can create docker image of running VM.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstand what docker does (or I misunderstand your question). Docker is not a VM provider; it's a container management mechanism based on libcontainer. In your case, I would do something like

- yum list installed
- download a base docker image for centos version X (or you could create one from scratch)
- pipe a subset of this output into a Dockerfile with yum install
- create your image
- if there are configs/non-RPM installs in your existing VM, either rebuild these in the container or worst case, share these
- your MySQL is easier to manage; as long as the database folder/partition can be copied & shared with docker, you may be able to install mysql and use this. Have done this with postgres a number of times and hoping mysql is similarly clean.

The nice thing is once you go through this exercise, you have a script that tells you exactly how you created your image.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am beginner with docker. So, did I understand correctly: we can not create image of CentOs with installed MySQL - we should install it every time when we create a new container?

Comment: An image is a thing you clone to create a container. You install once to make the image, and then you run that as many times as you wish. With a database in particular, you should probably mount the storage for the DB, because containers are supposed to be disposable/replaceable. You use a Dockerfile - which is basically a Makefile for building a docker image.

Comment: Asking how to convert a working VM image into a docker image is a very sound question, to get you started quickly.