# deploy container instance using azure VM image

Tags: docker, azure-devops, virtual-machine, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have captured the virtual machine and taken an image (generalized). I need to use that image to deploy the container. How to convert the VM image to a docker image or any other way?

Comment: Please find a duplicate question with answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307595/create-docker-image-from-existing-virtual-machine

Answer (score 0):

Docker is advantage version of virtualization,Docker uses container on host o.s to run application,It allow application to use the same linux kernal machine as a system on host computer rather than creating a whole virtual o.s.

You can push/upload the image to `container registry` and from there you can create the `container instance` using the below command.

```
az container create --resource-group v-rasxxxxxdtree --name mycontainer90 --image testmyacr90.azuXXXXxxxxxinx:latest --cpu 1 --memory 1 --registry-login-server testmyacr90.azurecr.io --registry-username TestMyAcr90 --registry-password CipBd5jooXXXXXXVEcyfZrbw/Pl --dns-name-label tesXXXinx5 --ports 80
```

Comment: how can I upload/push the VM image to the container registry?